# Cannot read properties of null (reading 'animate') error chrome JS animation

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I am new to webdev and I am trying to use this CodePen to animate my buttons:

https://codepen.io/Mamboleoo/pen/JjdXPgR

However, I am still getting this error on chrome when trying to run the code:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'animate')

I tried replacing the last JS line to: if ( document.getElementByID("aaa").animate ){} but no success.enter code here

Can anyone help me please ?
HTML

```
 <div class="contianer">
   <div class="wrapper" id="aaa">
   <button data-type="square">Square particles</button>
   <button data-type="emoji">Emoji particles</button>
   <button data-type="mario">Mario particles</button>
   <button data-type="shadow">Shadow particles</button>
   <button data-type="line">Line particles</button>
   </div>
   <span class="preloader"></span>
   </div>
```

CSS

```
particle {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
opacity: 0;
pointer-events: none;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: contain;
}

.wrapper {
position: absolute;
}
.wrapper button {
padding: 20px;
margin: 10px;
align-self: center;
}
.preloader {
 position: absolute;
 background: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/127738/mario-face.png);
  }
```

JS:

```
function pop (e) {
let amount = 30;
switch (e.target.dataset.type) {
case 'shadow':
case 'line':
  amount = 60;
  break;
}
// Quick check if user clicked the button using a keyboard
if (e.clientX === 0 && e.clientY === 0) {
const bbox = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
const x = bbox.left + bbox.width / 2;
const y = bbox.top + bbox.height / 2;
for (let i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
  // We call the function createParticle 30 times
  // We pass the coordinates of the button for x & y values
  createParticle(x, y, e.target.dataset.type);
}
} else {
for (let i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
  createParticle(e.clientX, e.clientY + window.scrollY, e.target.dataset.type);
}
}
}
function createParticle (x, y, type) {
const particle = document.createElement('particle');
document.body.appendChild(particle);
let width = Math.floor(Math.random() * 30 + 8);
let height = width;
let destinationX = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 300;
let destinationY = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 300;
let rotation = Math.random() * 520;
let delay = Math.random() * 200;

switch (type) {
case 'square':
  particle.style.background = `hsl(${Math.random() * 90 + 270}, 70%, 60%)`;
  particle.style.border = '1px solid white';
  break;
case 'emoji':
  particle.innerHTML = ['❤','','','','','',''][Math.floor(Math.random() * 7)];
  particle.style.fontSize = `${Math.random() * 24 + 10}px`;
  width = height = 'auto';
  break;
case 'mario':
  particle.style.backgroundImage = 'url(https://s3-us-west- 
2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/127738/mario-face.png)';
  break;
case 'shadow':
  var color = `hsl(${Math.random() * 90 + 90}, 70%, 50%)`;
  particle.style.boxShadow = `0 0 ${Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 10)}px ${color}`;
  particle.style.background = color;
  particle.style.borderRadius = '50%';
  width = height = Math.random() * 5 + 4;
  break;
case 'line':
  var color = `hsl(${Math.random() * 90 + 90}, 70%, 50%)`;
  particle.style.background = 'black';
  height = 1;
  rotation += 1000;
  delay = Math.random() * 1000;
  break;
}

particle.style.width = `${width}px`;
particle.style.height = `${height}px`;
const animation = particle.animate([
{
  transform: `translate(-50%, -50%) translate(${x}px, ${y}px) rotate(0deg)`,
  opacity: 1
},
{
  transform: `translate(-50%, -50%) translate(${x + destinationX}px, ${y + destinationY}px) 
 rotate(${rotation}deg)`,
  opacity: 0
 }
 ], {
duration: Math.random() * 1000 + 5000,
easing: 'cubic-bezier(0, .9, .57, 1)',
delay: delay
 });
 animation.onfinish = removeParticle;
 }
 function removeParticle (e) {
 e.srcElement.effect.target.remove();
 }

 if (document.body.animate) {
 document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(button => button.addEventListener('click', pop));
 }
```

Comment: sorry, no desire to look at ES4 unindented code